# Calling methods in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, function, methods

I am having 8 methods in my application, and each one is calling a single method -(void)someFunction,

How to know from inside the -(void)someFunction which one of those 8 methods called it ?

All suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add an int parameter to someFunction and the calling method can identify itself with a unique value.

For example:

```
-(void)someFunction:(int)callerId { //switch or if stmt here based on callerId }
```

Then calling method A would call someFunction with callerId 1, method B with callerId 2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Re-think your design.  Your methods should neither know nor care about the code that invokes them.  Anything they need to know should be in the parameters they receive.

Answer (score 1):

This seems easy--pass an argument to the function that determines which method it was.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Objective C, but it seems like you want a stack trace.  You might be able to get this by throwing an exception.  (Some languages have a way of getting at the stack trace in other ways, but like I said, I'm not familiar enough with Objective C to know.)  [Related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220159/how-do-you-print-out-a-stack-trace-to-the-console-log-in-cocoa).